# Non-zero monoid

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose a set of generators and relations of a monoid (possibly infinite) is given. How do you show that the monoid is non-zero ? I mean is there an easy way to produce a non-zero element ?

Comment: The corresponding question for groups is "unsolvable" in the sense that it is a theorem that there is no algorithm (in the sense of something you can program into a computer) which is guaranteed to produce a non-zero element iff the group is non-zero. In short: don't expect an easy way that will work in general -- you have to get lucky and spot a trick that will work in your case.

Comment: What do you know about the monoid or its presentation?

Comment: wccanard, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know. Your are probably talking about the 'word problem for groups' ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups ). That is given an element in terms of generators, decide whether it is the trivial element. Correct me if i am wrong. Jacks questions is slightly different and asks for the existence of a non-trivial element. This may be much easier. And also the above problem is decidable for many groups and only undecidable 'in worst case'. So it really depends the monoid in consideration.

Comment: Wccanard is talking about the fact that it is undecidable given a finite group presentation as input whether the group with that presentation is trivial. Since finite group presentations can effectively be turned into finite monoid presentations, this is also undecidable for monoids. 

Comment: Stephan, it's not much easier -- a presented group will have a nontrivial element iff one of its generators is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks, your are right. Somehow I missed that. I am not sure if the OP has such answers in mind, but here [ http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mkambites/events/bmc2008/kambites.pdf ](pdf) is a survey of 'not-so-bad/good' presentations and their word problems.

Answer (score 3):

You construct a surjective homomorphism to a non-zero monoid.

Comment: In other words, find a nonzero monoid whose generators obey the given relations. For the problem stated in this generality, I can't think of a better general answer. 